# Why is my property's accessor being ignored?

Tags: c#, properties, getter

I have declared a property like so:

```
private int? platypusLocalId;

public int? PlatypusLocalId
{
    get
    {
        return GetPlatypusLocalIDForPlatypusID(platypusID);
    }
}
```

...expecting any reference to platypusLocalId, such as this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> duckBillPairs = GetAvailableDuckBillsForPlatypus(platypusLocalId);
```

...to call the accessor/getter; however, it is not being called and platypusLocalId is thus null when passed into GetAvailableDuckBillsForPlatypus().

Comment: I would avoid having the only difference between my private field and public property be case.

Comment: I tried to delete this, as I just realized I was passing platypusLocalId when I should have been passing PlatypusLocalId.

Comment: @Nate: Isn't that the canonical way of doing it? Besides, that's what ReSharper does automatically when you create, say, "private int flockOfPelicansCount" and then right-click and select "Refactor | Encapsulate Field"

Comment: @Nate: Followup; IOW, it would create a "FlockOfPelicansCount"; and if you started off with "private int FlockOfPelicansCount" it would convert it to "private int flockOfPelicansCount" before creating the corresponding "public int FlockOfPelicansCount"

Comment: I tend to use an underscore. This avoids any confusion. It is a personal preference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your case -- you're accessing the field `platypusLocalId` directly, not the property `PlatypusLocalId`. The field will be null as you haven't assigned it.

Answer (score 5):

Any reference to PlatypusLocalId will call the getter.
However, you are using platypusLocalId (note the lowercase p), which means you are accessing the private field directly.

Properties aren't just used magically - you have to call them!